# Vue3 - delayed transition

Tags: vuejs3, vue-transitions

I am trying to develop an animation which will sequentially load into the view once the side bar is toggled on

The animation should be similar to this one: https://codepen.io/dizzyluo/pen/yJLwWm

Here is my code:

**Parent:**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="cartToggle">Toggle</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <Child :visible="cartVisible" @update:visible="cartToggle" />
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Child from './Comp.vue'

const cartVisible = ref(false)
const cartToggle = () => {
  cartVisible.value = !cartVisible.value
}
</script>
<style scoped>
span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

**Child:**

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { toRefs, watchEffect, onBeforeUnmount } from 'vue'
import CartItem from './CartItem.vue'

const props = defineProps({
  visible: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false
  }
})

const { visible } = toRefs(props)

const emit = defineEmits(['update:visible'])

const hideCartBar = () => {
  emit('update:visible', false)
}

watchEffect(() => {
  document.body.style.overflow = visible.value ? 'hidden' : 'auto'
  document.body.style.paddingRight = visible.value ? '15px' : '0px'
})

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'
  document.body.style.paddingRight = '0px'
})
const show = true
</script>

<template>
  <transition name="fade">
    <div
      v-if="props.visible"
      class="cartbar-overlay"
      @click="hideCartBar"
    ></div>
  </transition>
  <transition name="slide">
    <div v-show="props.visible" class="cartbar-container">
      <div class="cartbar__header">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <span @click="hideCartBar" class="cursor-pointer">X</span>
      </div>
      <div class="cart-items">
        <CartItem v-for="index in 3" :key="index" :delay="index" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<style scoped>
/* transition */
.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-to,
.fade-leave-from {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.slide-enter-from,
.slide-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.slide-enter-to,
.slide-leave-from {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.slide-enter-active,
.slide-leave-active {
  transition: transform 500ms;
}
/* cartbar */
.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cartbar-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cartbar-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 460px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: calc(4px * 7);
  background-color: #f4f2f1;
  color: #706b5f;
}

.cartbar__header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
</style>
```

**Delayed animated component:**

```html
<script setup>
import { toRefs } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  delay: Number
})

const { delay } = toRefs(props)
</script>

<template>
  <transition appear name="slide">
    <div class="item">
      {{ delay }}
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/75x100" />
      </div>
      <div class="meta">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <div class="meta-info">
          <p>Dolor sit amet dorum forum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<style scoped>
.slide-leave-active,
.slide-enter-active {
  transition: 1s;
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.slide-enter {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}
.slide-leave-to {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.meta-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.image {
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 100%;
}

.image img {
  height: 100%;
}

.meta-info {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
</style>
```

Any idea what am I missing there?

[Playground Link](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqtV21v2zYQ/iuchqFuEUlO07SD53htunzosHVF2w0FpqGgJcpmI5EaSTn2gvz33ZGSTEl2tmBDXyCSd8fn3p6jb4NXVRVtahbMgrlhZVVQwxaJIGSe8Y39gM9lbYwU5GVa8PT6IglSqsxHuVoVLAkW7mMeOyGnG7fKvpXXa15k7puQ2YZrvixYY+03t0qC9vxlXWUAZSDWXuqk4t5l89jDD0udKl4ZopmpK9jhZSWVIbdEsZzckVzJkiQBeJ4E33WnFmJ7FsWvZWmDY0USkUqhDfHgkgu0NslpodljENkLOKBwPnlMLhbkFoF6itGGFjUefzXaBDN38G8eO/zOl6/CkLzKMgClU1mxLAkINUZxiDkjRpKClxzQf/iAC7PmmqQAXQomDJGi2JEwxAhpswNQzgSsdUVFA61WWqoZqSQXhinEYCGg/CI4CQzoiJyvoi9aCigVqwQpgUt4wdQvleHgehLMnDk8o0Uhb360e0bV7KTdT9csvT6w/0VvcS8J3immmdpA0LszQ9WKGXd89eEt28J3d1jKrMaauOfwPdOyqBGjE7usRQawPTmL9o0tAi5WH/XV1jChW6cQKEreWXlbNVgax1zfwz2LzqwexBOi2JYT9ppfnaSgYgUVbsCMX6lGvme5PiE31KTrqzxnqTmBdF6yXCr2qyhlDek9WspQWG+gI9zxIyjmZgMRPPLquVKy0lCKGcu5YO9wNbGuNK3XOWZ2FSwupSwYFU3kFPuz5oplvWSCJVoXZkZsY9hNjNwdtkh7621rHhy4aDydWCi+FMOybqFdwUJPfk+CPjUkwR++yppnDF29pKrffmhrMlY+cSjRBPZdIrxoTzz1TKZ1Cf0ULWW2i2xnRHLDVA6FAxc19prG/h7yAUAyBgVHsOJobaTNzmFDFc0yqLv3fLVGf8fGTs8raA9raopfiNZ5PaiHB0B+KKrB1S7cem1tYfZHrNWbJ3YEGEWhq7BjiKAlsnpOMxwirYSbGPsVVGHIc5CzpRF1WfMl0oJq3QyIJVUhuljQXV+om11effgSi/3MsijiPdT74OsCzI3wA2iMyxj2CCsE0VCobcDi2WisDIQ/f14ziNZQFITXTxc/M1HPY/gYHFmOP+z83r5l/7AhfzD/CfIIen1EvfgcxBhyyLjjsB6Gjoo2IVQqCHORsS3hgpxhTV+zXbuHy4xB8rwNN+WPwbg3baMnQX/+xU+gbruMPokTEWE5htAGTIXIm8Babgsob8NCGK62sWRFU252MzJ1k7KvaORAzTJwX/H0kCJNDd8gX/rKbtOp79HOWlPkfDotdWfN1uPAAbfX98BagmSUSNzwiTH6NDmdTr+xRDiy5XzyLe2dOmxretjQ3kff2DEnO9O+m5C2piNczvrle8+DBmX7HOGEK9nel/MtyywfGlm59MKMQ/5rF0sJr1zw1K0Klu9PaHq9UsDBGXR1gZer1ZJOpiek+Ru9wJAcwdYh6xjhv2K74ZlZQ6VBTu26pNuw2Xv2HJjcbq6ZM9BJtfNhhoMU5lejqlZcQK7QWxwadrcZDzPIRpFOnlVb8oQ0Lo5j8XX+LH+aY9lDAJqtF9Pny/N8mJuW5poZxjU0MHRMXjAHGT/CDB4dUDMYFyVv7P6XWhue72wAodZmBCgsZeGSmRsGc9h/0SYCX2Pee2j4Ihu/wsbvrH98P1kim5G3dblkavz+sccHXz/3TFF/BNGqYtADBydRj5uRlvesfHtrb76DeBzgcV7S1WCg8XJFtEpxfBhT6VkcA56UrWWRRamMX5xvoXp6RD0gZd9+yQztm1+fLX6C90tJ3lS6LmGGnQ2nqa8bcpHDm6U/E6rFD1hSBAJDIBoGXjOqhpcv/j+PMZvHxoX383T/m/VBQ+QAj+3Zzee8MbudIqH5W2FTMtPo6XlDdr6h43RrmRsopuHcf035k7Cv2P6JulD/v13osUlLUx2LNLM0wmp96K2tyVPgNW8o22J2thoKa/gSn9OH+M9Xw7K3qr5MKzKITw7ehpr/Bb+PptG3UMz9X9DAN3d/Ax+W0aY=)

Comment: You're passing the delay to `<CartItem />` but you're not using it in the inner `<Transition />`, you're only displaying it in the template. Currently you're applying the same delay to all items, via CSS: `0.25s`. Do not expect Vue to adjust the inner `<Transition />`'s delay based on a prop's value, just because the prop's name is `delay`. Also note you'll need to multiply the delay passed to the `<Transition />` as differences in delay of `1ms` will not make a difference to the human eye.

Comment: Last, but not least, if you want the staggering to happen after the sidebar opened, you need to not render the items while the Sidebar is closed and to inflate the `delay` by how much the Sidebar takes to open, in each cart item.

Comment: I suggest having a look at [staggering-list-transitions](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group#staggering-list-transitions) in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need add v-show or v-if on <div class="item"> if you want the transition  working correctly.
2. You need  rename the transition in components CartItem because the parent has a same name slide,and it affects the child elements.
3. The props appear is usually used in a element that showing at first but not like this case,so I implement this function by add a ref isFirst.

[check the Playground Link](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)